How to handle currency values properly?
I have a system where all the transaction amount are being stored in integer(cent).
This has been working fine so far, with over 20 million transactions already recorded.
However, I’ve recently encountered a use case where the equivalent integer value becomes zero after converting to cents, leading to issues with small amounts
# Models
class Wallet(models.Model):
    balance = models.IntegerField()

class WalletTransaction(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()  # Stored in cents
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

# Updating wallet balance and creating transaction
cost_price = 0.0025 
cost_price_in_cents = cost_price * 100  # Converts to 0.25 cents
wallet = Wallet.objects.get(id=1)
wallet.balance -= cost_price_in_cents
wallet.save()
WalletTransaction.objects.create(wallet=wallet, amount=cost_price_in_cents)

Here balance gets deducted by 0.25 but in wallet transaction history it is 0.

use decimal field ie balance = models.DecimalField()

Or you need to multiply the data by 10000 to be able to handle fraction of cents. This is more of a business question - if you only one to store up to cents, then why do you have such small prices that result in less than a cent value and if the amount is less than a cent, then do you truly care about that transaction.

The reason to use integers is to avoid floating-point arithmetic. If you are allowing quarter-cent currency amounts, you need to use a smaller base unit than once cent internally. (The TeX typesetting system uses this approach. "Normal" units like cm and points are used to specify font sizes, distances, etc, but internally all measurements and calculations are done using scaled points, which are something like 3 µm: any rounding error involving such calculations is far below the precision offered by even extremely high-end printing devices.)

You should make transition to Decimal fields. With current solution you could do this with 2 steps:

Add new decimal field:

class Wallet(models.Model):
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    balance_decimal = models.DecimalField(null=True)

class WalletTransaction(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()  # Stored in cents
    amount_decimal = models.DecimalField(null=True)
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

make a migration to add new fields

After starting storing everything as decimal, you are ready to make a transition with migration. Here is example of migration file:

from django.db import migrations, transaction

def populate_decimal_fields(apps, schema_editor):
    Wallet = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'Wallet')
    WalletTransaction = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'WalletTransaction')

    with transaction.atomic():
        for wallet in Wallet.objects.select_for_update():
            wallet.balance_decimal = wallet.balance/100
            wallet.save(update_fields=["balance_decimal"])

        for transaction in WalletTransaction.objects.select_for_update():
            transaction.amount_decimal = transaction.amount/ 100
            transaction.save(update_fields=["amount_decimal"])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app_name', 'previous_migration_file'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_decimal_fields),
    ]

Note: Its not well optimised as all wallets and transactions are blocked with select_for_update
